# Boost includes wreaks havoc - but it's not Boost's fault

Tags: c++, boost

I am introducing Boost into my project and as soon as I include Boost headers (`#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>`) in a particular file I get errors in the boost headers.

Here is a short snippet of the errors:

```
1>c:\boost\include\boost-1_57\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp(28): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\boost\include\boost-1_57\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp(28): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'sizeof'
1>c:\boost\include\boost-1_57\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp(26): error C3747: missing default template parameter : parameter 2
1>c:\boost\include\boost-1_57\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp(40): error C2974: 'boost::mpl::if_' : invalid template argument for 'T2', type expected
1>          c:\boost\include\boost-1_57\boost\mpl\if.hpp(56) : see declaration of 'boost::mpl::if_'
1>          c:\boost\include\boost-1_57\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp(44) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::eval_if<C,__formal>' being compiled
1>c:\boost\include\boost-1_57\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp(40): error C2974: 'boost::mpl::if_' : invalid template argument for 'T3', type expected
1>          c:\boost\include\boost-1_57\boost\mpl\if.hpp(56) : see declaration of 'boost::mpl::if_'
1>c:\boost\include\boost-1_57\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp(50): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\boost\include\boost-1_57\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp(50): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'sizeof'
1>c:\boost\include\boost-1_57\boost\mpl\eval_if.hpp(62): error C2974: 'boost::mpl::if_c' : invalid template argument for 'T1', type expected
```

I immediately thought about namespace collision and I removed all `using namespace std`, but this didn't solve the problem. I have used Boost threads in another location and it worked as expected (but that code is now inactive and not being built).

Any hints?

--- Some notes

1. Running in VS2013
2. Code without `using namespace std` builds and works

Comment: What happens if you included the boost headers in a simple hello word application?

Comment: Without seeing the header/source file you're including this in, it's going to be very hard to diagnose a problem.

Comment: Which compiler version? And with which flags? Seems like a `/Za`-related problem.

Comment: I'd suggest reverting to the version prior to your including the Boost headers, making sure that compiles, and then removing `using namespace std;` (and maybe other using directives, if any). Once you get that to compile try including the Boost headers.

Comment: @NathanOliver. No problem using  boost at all. This is definitely something to do with my code

Comment: The only thing I can think of is there is an error in one of your header files that is being included before a boost header.  I have seen that make it look like the error is in the header included after.  One thing you might be able to do to help find the problem is to include all system and boost headers first and then include your own headers.

Comment: @NathanOliver. Good call. Just moved the boost includes before the stl includes and that solved it. Put this in an answer and I'll accept it as the right one ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is there is an error in one of your header files that is being included before a boost header. I have seen that make it look like the error is in the header included after. One thing you might be able to do to help find the problem is to include all system and boost headers first and then include your own headers.